# renderDataTable Select all cells containing value > 10 and highlight

Tags: jquery, r, datatables, shiny

I'm creating a dataTable that has a user-defined number of rows & columns. I would like to loop through all of the cells in the table (minus the first column, which contains names) and highlight/change CSS if values are greater than 10. Shiny has a great example of targeting a specific column (see below). I'm assuming I'd need to write some sort of jQuery function? I'm a complete jQuery newbie, so I gave it a try, and, it obviously hasn't worked (also see below). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Shiny example of targeting a specific column:

```
rowCallback = I(
  'function(row, data) {
    // Bold cells for those >= 5 in the first column
    if (parseFloat(data[0]) >= 5.0)
      $("td:eq(0)", row).css("font-weight", "bold");
  }'
)
```

My failed attempt at writing a function to loop through cells:

```
rowCallback = I('
               function(row, data) {
               for each (i in 1:1000) {
               if (parseFloat(data[i]) > 10.0)
               $("td:eq(i)", row).css("color", "red");}
               }')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to implement it with this (without installing DT):

```
rowCallback = I(
    'function(row, data) {
        $("td", row).each(function(i) {
            if (i == 0) return; // first column is row names
            if (parseFloat(data[i]) >= 10.0)
                $(this).css("color", "red");
        });
    }'
)
```

Comment: Yup. Basically did the same. Are data tables actually getting deprecated?

Comment: `shiny::renderDataTable()` will be deprecated and we will continue the development in the **DT** package, so `I()` will stop working in the future (use `DT::renderDataTable()` and `JS()` instead).

Answer (score 1):

`for each (i in 1:1000)` does not look like valid JavaScript syntax. Here is a minimal example using the [**DT**](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package (the DataTables functions in **shiny** will be deprecated in future). It may be slightly difficult to understand if you are not familiar with JavaScript (our goal is to [make it easier](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/31) in future).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('foo')),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$foo = renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, options = list(
        rowCallback = JS(
          'function(row, data) {',
          '$("td", row).each(function(i) {',
            'if (i == 0) return; // first column is row names',
            'if (parseFloat(data[i]) >= 3.0)',
              '$(this).css("color", "red");',
          '});',
          '}')
      ))
    })
  }

)
```

[image: DT rowCallback]

To install **DT** at this moment, you need:

```
install.packages(
  c("DT", "shiny")
  type = "source",
  repos = c("http://yihui.name/xran", "http://cran.rstudio.com")
)
```

You will be able to install everything normally from CRAN after **DT** is on CRAN.

Comment: Thank you Yihui! That answered my question!