# DT datatable row is not highlighted when using custom callback in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794738/shiny-getting-info-from-the-selected-row-in-a-dt-data-table) of how to get elements from a row that is clicked on. This works fine except it does not highlight the selected row. Here is the code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tab'), verbatimTextOutput('row')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tab = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, selection = 'single',
                callback = JS("table.on('click.dt', 'tr',
                                function() {
                                  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                                  Shiny.onInputChange('row', table.rows('.selected').data().toArray());
                                });")
      )
    })
    output$row = renderText({input$row})
  }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not existed in DT `input$..._rows_selected` ?
like

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tab'), verbatimTextOutput('row')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tab = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(iris, selection = "single"
      )
    })
    output$row = renderText({if(length(input$tab_rows_selected)>0) paste(input$tab_rows_selected,as.character(iris[input$tab_rows_selected,]))})
  }
      ))
```

## Update

for example your have dunamic data

```
dt1=reactive({
return(iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),])})
```

There may be any other data operation

than your code will be

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tab'), verbatimTextOutput('row')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    dt1=reactive({
      return(iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"),])})
    output$tab = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(dt1(), selection = "single"
      )
    })
    output$row = renderText({if(length(input$tab_rows_selected)>0) paste(input$tab_rows_selected,as.character(dt1()[input$tab_rows_selected,]))})
  }
      ))
```

My `DT` version 0.1.45

## Update 2

dont know why but i think `$(this).toggleClass('selected');` 
delete class selected which added in standart DT package(`toggleClass` used twice and you see nothing) .

try

```
JS("table.on('click.dt', 'tr',
                              function() {
                                                           Shiny.onInputChange('row', table.rows(this).data().toArray());
                              });")
```

Or set `selection='none'`

Comment: `iris` data here is just an example. In a real app datatable is generated dynamically.

Comment: input$tab_rows_selected return row number from your data and your can all row data if want. ( going to add example)

Comment: In your case you need to call a function `dt1` twice to render table and to get the value.

Comment: Ok didn't know that.